# T4 compiler puts comments in code before a '['

Tags: t4

I've got a T4 template that writes a DTO construct for my classes.  I decided to add the following code to the template:

```
    <# if( prop.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name.ToLower() == "datetime" ) { #>
    <#=    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}")] #>
<# } #>
```

when I compile it I get an error saying: ") expected".  When I look at the intermediate code that T4 built I see the following:

> ```
>             #line 55 "C:\Users\Lou\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\...\DTO_Generator.tt"
>             this.Write(Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.ToStringHelper.ToStringWithCulture(//[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}")]));
> ```

Apparently the compiler is putting a "//" before the "[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}")] " that I want to insert which is removing the ')' which is at the end of that line.

I've tried to escape and double the "[" which I assume is causing the problem.

Any ideas on how to avoid having T4 puting those "//" into the code?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do. The `<#= ... #>` code evaluates the `...` as a string and outputs it. If you explicitly want `[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}")]` to be output, then you should use:

```
<# if( prop.TypeUsage.EdmType.Name.ToLower() == "datetime" ) { #>
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:mm/dd/yyyy}")]
<# } #>
```